Qt for iOS Lottie SplashScreen
У меня есть следующая задача: нужно реализовать Lottie SplashScreen при старте qt-ios приложения.
@interface QIOSApplicationDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end


@interface QIOSApplicationDelegate (EveryDayApplicationDelegate)
@end

@implementation QIOSApplicationDelegate (EveryDayApplicationDelegate)
// ...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SplashViewController *splashVC = [[SplashViewController alloc] init];
    window.rootViewController = splashVC;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.window = window;

    return true;
}
//...
@end

Этот код заставляет приложение просто зависнуть, никакое окно не открывается. В чистом objective-c приложении работает как надо.
Как сделать это в qt for iOS?
